# Getting this error in VSCode: no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error message in VSCode:

```
no operator "<<" matches these operands C/C++(349)
PrintingAlternate.cpp(21, 9): operand types are: std::ostream << void
```

Help me to fix this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(int ar[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i=i+2){
        cout<<ar[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }
}
        
void print(int ar[], int n){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<ar[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }
}
        
int main()
{
    int ar[4]={1,2,3,4};
    cout<<"The Normal array are: ";
    cout<<print(ar, 4);
    cout<<"The Reverse array are: "<< reverse(ar, 4);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does reverse(ar, 4) return?

Comment: `cout<<print(ar, 4);`  but `print` returns void.  What do you want it to output here?

Comment: Both `print` and `reverse` are `void` so you can't do `std::cout << print(ar, 4);` - also, `reverse` doesn't seem to reverse anything. It just skips every other value when printing the array.

Comment: From the looks of your functions, I'd guess that you wanted `print(ar,4);` and **not** `cout<<print(ar,4);`, which means "display the value returned from calling `print(ar,4)`".  That returned value is `void`, as your error tells you, which is not something that can be displayed.

Comment: A similar question was asked earlier today: [Why function is displaying error when declared with a void return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621190/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` and `reverse()` both return `void`, ie nothing, so there is no value available for `main()` to pass to `operator<<`.  They both do their own printing internally, so `main()` should not be trying to pass their return values to `operator<<` at all.

Try this instead:

```
int main()
{
    int ar[4]={1,2,3,4};
    cout<<"The Normal array are: ";
    print(ar, 4);
    cout<<"The Reverse array are: ";
    reverse(ar, 4);
        
    return 0;
}
```